# Diamond in Java with input (using nested for loops or some conditional if statements)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have to ask for an input and display a diamond with that many lines. I have a code but it displays less lines than I input. I'm confused with where I'm going wrong?

This is the code I have currently:

### Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PROBLEM3 {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input number of lines:");
        int i = 0, j, k, n;
        n = scan.nextInt();


        for(k = 0; k <= n / 2; k++){
            for (i = 0; i <  n - k; i++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (j = 1; j < k; j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (j = 1; j < k - 1 ; j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }

        for (k = (n / 2); k <= n ; k++){
            for (i = 0; i < k; i++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for ( i = 1; i < n - k ; i++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (j = 0; j < n - k - 2; j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
 Please input number of lines:
 5


 *
 ***
 *
```

Comment: Provide the output you are getting with this code

Comment: Can the number of lines be either even or odd? Or do you need to check that it's one or the other?

Comment: I have to make it work for any number greater than zero. Does that mean I have to use if statements to change the # of lines

Comment: Write out (with pen and paper) how many of what you want it to print on each line. From there it shouldn't be too difficult to construct the loops.

Comment: @zoe, please add explaining comments to your original post. Please also add any info on how you've tried to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the below code,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PROBLEM3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input number of lines:");
        int i = 0, j, k, n;
        n = scan.nextInt();

        for (k = 1; k <= (n + 1) / 2; k++) {
            for (i = 0; i < n - k; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        for (k = ((n + 1) / 2); k < n; k++) {
            for (i = 1; i < k; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (j = 0; j < n - k; j++) {
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I understand why just dividing by two wouldn't work. I played around with it and now it prints out the correct # of lines, but only for odd #s. I am confused as to how to make it also work for even #s?

Comment: hey, I believe the above code works for even input too, please let me know if something is wrong

Comment: if i input 5 it outputs 6 lines for a diamond so i changed the first four loop so that it had k < (n+1)/2 which mkaes it wokr for odd # but it doesnt work for even

Comment: just now tested my code again, it prints only 5 lines for input 5. can  you check the code again with out any code changes

Comment: I just had to rewrite it. It works on a new class I made but not on the one I was working on for some reason. Thank you for the help, I realize where I went wrong with the conditions